# Anyone know of a set of C# bindings for FFMPEG?

Tags: c#, .net, binding, ffmpeg

Does anyone know of a set of bindings for C# to drive the FFMpeg library directly ? I could shell to ffmpeg.exe directly but I found it hard to sync/control as a separate process. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tao.ffmpeg: http://www.taoframework.com/project/ffmpeg
it compiles and has a binary dist which is more than can be said for ffmpeg-sharp at this point. It is, however, not particularly easy to use.

Comment: This one actually works. Unfortunately the function signatures aren't set up for automatic marshalling; expect lots of `IntPtr` parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately TAO Framework project is gone.

Comment: Well, "gone" is not the right word... you can still retrieve all versions from the SF archive [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/taoframework/files/The%20Tao%20Framework/)

Answer (score 7):

I've seen this library:

[**ffmpeg-sharp**](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/) a wrapper library over the FFmpeg multimedia suite that provides easy to use wrappers for use in C#.

Comment: I just checkout latest version of ffmpeg-sharp and it doesn't compile :-(

Comment: The Interop part compiles & works fine.

Comment: So it's been quite a while (over 3 years) since I was last able to tackle the project and I know this question is very old, but I just wanted to post that I've made a major update to the library and that it now compiles and the examples work.  Hopefully it will work well for your project or others that might see this.

Comment: @JustinCherniak Thanks, I hope you'll continue developing your wrapper. Few good alternatives out there

Comment: Currently compiles but doesn't run http://stackoverflow.com/q/15625981/340760

Comment: same issue, the sample player compiles but throws an exception as soon as I try to play a standard mp4 or anything else.

Comment: Link broken now?

Answer (score 5):

It's actually pretty easy to control as a separate process. If you redirect StandardOut and StandardError then you can subscribe to the Process.OnData* events and receive the command line output. It's then trivial enough to parse the status line using a regex and work out things like % complete and so on.

The hardest thing is working out what command line to pass to get decent quality! I'd recommend [this page](http://rob.opendot.cl/index.php/useful-stuff/ffmpeg-x264-encoding-guide/) and [this page](http://ffmpeg.x264.googlepages.com/mapping) if you're using H.264/AAC+.

Comment: Great tip, Greg. Links don't work, so maybe just Google "ffmpeg-x264-encoding-guide" (without the quotes).

Comment: Too bad there's no option to make it accept / output XML or JSON or something standardized (a few command line apps, like bzr for example, are doing this now, since it makes it easier to automate them). -- Also FFMPEG sometimes updates the same line repeatedly, or inserts newlines and repeats the info non-deterministically... might make it really hard to automate this way.

Answer (score 4):

http://jasonjano.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ffmpeg/