# video conversion in C#

Tags: c#, video

Iam writing an application which will do Conversion from AVI to MPEG, WMV to AVI, WMV to MPEG or H.264/AVC video, AVI to MP4, RMVB to 3GP, etc.

I am looking for C# code and tutorials for the same.

Any pointers will be really helpful.

Comment: What have you found in your searching so far?

Comment: I googled a lot , but google seemed filled with paid libs and stuff. I want to write some thing from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are fine with using [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org), you may want to look at answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271003/anyone-know-of-a-set-of-c-bindings-for-ffmpeg).

Answer (score 1):

You can use DirectShow, see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/MediaFilesConversionCS.aspx), google with directshow for other conversions

Answer (score 1):

As Rohit mentioned use and download ffmpeg.exe  from [here](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/ffmpeg)

I have used it several times and made conversion, 2 pass filtering, created frames, preview images.