# Using FFmpeg from .NET

Tags: .net, video, ffmpeg

I have been searching for an hour on how to use FFmpeg from .NET and it seems you need to execute the FFmpeg.exe with a Process to get things done. To get a duration of an flv file for instance, you would need to start using grep to get something back out of cmd window. It all seems complicated... + you'd have to start installing things on remote servers (@ customers)...

Is there another way? Aren't there dll's containing the FFmpeg logic? Other solutions to get some information out of flv files in .NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anyone know of a set of C# bindings for FFMPEG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271003/anyone-know-of-a-set-of-c-bindings-for-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out [ffmpeg-sharp](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/)?

Comment: Great, hadn't found it with google. Thx. Will check it tomorrow.