# Create a Video Stream (AVI) from a Series of Images

Tags: .net, vb.net, video-streaming, jpeg, avi

There is an IP web camera that I wrote a .NET class for sometime ago.  It's basically a Timer implementation that pings a snapshot CGI script from the camera every five seconds.  The camera itself is very rudamentary; it does not have any sort of API for me to work with, the only thing I can do programmatically (remotely)  is invoke this script.  The script returns a 640x480 JPEG image.  Simple.

Now what I need to be able to do is take a days worth of these images, and create a "time lapse" AVI video stream out of it that will eventually be embedded into a web page. How can I do this with VB.NET?

Comment: Check out this project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx

Comment: Nice!!  Are you the same nobugz from MSDN forums?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

.net doesn't directly support video formats. Your best option would be to use a 3rd party tool to generate the .avi.

ffmpeg is one option. You could access it directly via a command line like this:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i img%d.jpg /output/a.mpg
```

You would need to name your images img1.jpg, img2.jpg etc. For more details see the [ffmpeg faq](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f). You should also find details in the faq for how to output different video formats.

You can start a process from vb using [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx). Something like this:

```
Process.Start("ffmpeg.exe", "-f image2 -i img%d.jpg /output/a.mpg")
```

You could also take a look at [ffmpeg-sharp](http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/) or [Tao.FFmpeg](http://www.taoframework.com/project/ffmpeg), they are .net wrappers for the ffmpeg libraries. I haven't tried either personally, but it looks like it might help you out.

Another alternative would be to take a look at [MEncoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html), which has similar functionality. You should be able to look up a similar command line for this tool.

[Related SO question: [271003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271003/anyone-know-of-a-set-of-c-bindings-for-ffmpeg)]

Comment: Looks like a good solution.  Was hoping for a library, but I can launch this separate process no problem.

Comment: @Josh. I've added some links to wrapper libraries that you might want to check out.

Comment: ffmpeg-sharp does not compile, and I can't find anyplace to download Tao.FFmpeg

Comment: I think I'll just launch the process myself.  I've done this before with LAME MP3 audio encoder, so I am somewhat familiar with it.

Comment: TAO download is here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/taoframework/, but if you're happy with doing it on the command line, that probably is the easiest way.

Answer (score 4):

FFMpeg has windows binaries and is very popular.

[Making movies from image files using ffmpeg/mencoder](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/)

You'll have to check whether the available output formats suit you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a C# wrapper by someone at Codeproject:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx

That wrapper should provide you with what you need.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't there when I posted this answer (hadn't refreshed the page)

Answer (score 0):

There are several command-line tools that can take a series of images and output an AVI file. I would suggest you call one of them from your app.

I would provide links to suggestions, but it has been years since I've used one.

Edit: apparently you can do this using ffmpeg: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html

> For creating a video from many images:
>
> ffmpeg -f image2 -i foo-%03d.jpeg -r
>   12 -s WxH foo.avi
>
> The syntax foo-%03d.jpeg specifies to
>   use a decimal number composed of three
>   digits padded with zeroes to express
>   the sequence number. It is the same
>   syntax supported by the C printf
>   function, but only formats accepting a
>   normal integer are suitable.