# Server Side Compilation for .mp4 and .swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video

I was looking at this website www.goanimate.com which generates a .mp4 animated movie through user data that is collected through a .swf GUI.

I was trying to see if anyone had an idea/direction of how a .mp4 could be generated server side and then presented to the user for download. Additionally, I was also wondering if a .swf could be compiled though this manner as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mp4 can be created with ffmpeg from a series of images.  Here's a sample from [FFMPEG - Stream series of images into MP4 with sound synchronization at specified frame rate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665774/ffmpeg-stream-series-of-images-into-mp4-with-sound-synchronization-at-specifie)

> Here is an example invocation of ffmpeg that takes frames named sphere00.png through sphere29.png together with one second audio track audio.wav and creates an out.mp4 file that shows the frames at 30 fps together with the sound.

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -f image2 -i "sphere%02d.png" -i audio.wav out.mp4
```

swf can be created on-demand from [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html) source using the mxmlc compiler (which can embed images or be generated dynamically easily).

Other swf options include [swfmill](http://swfmill.org/) and [haxe](http://haxe.org)

Comment: Thank you Samuel, so to utilize these libraries would I then in turn have to run a shell script on the server passing the required vars in order to get these compiled and saved to the server for access?

Comment: @user2723341, you need some server side programming environment, hopefully something much more powerful than a shell script.  Node, Ruby, PHP, .NET, Java, something.