# converting image sequence to video

Tags: c++, c, video, sequence, flv

I want to make a screen capture utility, so far i am able to capture the screen in regular interval to get a numbered sequence of images and now i want to encode them to a video format preferably flv(because of good compression and web support)
....I tried the ffmpeg.exe for that reason but for some strange reason it did'nt work
on my vista ultimate...only the first picture is encoded while the rest -I dont know what happened to them.

Also I would prefer doing the encoding stuf programatically (using c/c++ library api if any for that purpose) rather than using tools as ffmpeg.exe and i am interested in encoding picture sequence to video not capturing contineouse video directly.

I searched through internet....there are lots of libraries and tutorial for converting between video formats but I did'nt find something usefull for my problem.

I am not verry proficient with video formats and sdk library, I just need a quick way to encode some pictures to video with some basic control (as time interval between two consecutive frames).
So can you help me with some pointers as to which library i should use and how(code fragment and little descriptive answer would greatly help) and please dont recomend any .NET solution I need to learn something out of this and dont want to apply some bruteforce approach to solve the problem.

Sorry for my english....and thanks in advance.

Comment: `mencoder` with the `mf://` source would be my first try.

Comment: i have did same stuff in matlab & stored in .avi with matlab api check my project http://shareprogrammingtips.com/matlab-related-stuff/audiovideo-recorder-player-application-based-on-matlab/

Answer (score 2):

It appears that an .avi file can more or less directly be made of .jpg's:
[*An AVI file may carry audio/visual data inside the chunks in virtually any compression scheme, including Full Frame (Uncompressed)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Video_Interleave), ..., [**Motion JPEG**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG).

Also, [something very similar has been discussed here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870103/create-a-video-stream-avi-from-a-series-of-images).