# Convert all video format to 3gp and mpeg4 video format?

Tags: c#, video

Right now i stuck in my application because of this issue.

anyone help to get out of this.

Want source code to covert all video format to 3gp and mpeg4 format.

i developed this applicatoin on asp.net using c# as a backend language.

Comment: Please provide a lot more information on what you have done to solve this and what the issues are with your solution.

Comment: i am just started R&D on it. i dont know anything about. it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**ffmpeg**](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) is a command-line binary for both Unix/Linux and Windows, and is the standard tool for video conversion.

To get startd, check out [**this forum entry**](http://www.videohelp.com/forum/archive/ffmpeg-3gp-t336282.html) related to 3gp conversion.

Check [**this SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271003/anyone-know-of-a-set-of-c-bindings-for-ffmpeg) on how to integrate ffmpeg with C#.

Comment: ffmpeg convert into 3gp only. want to convert into both 3gp and mpeg through commandline.

Comment: What are you talking about? Of course ff*mpeg* can convert video to mpeg.