# Video Conversion in .net

Tags: c#, vb.net

i want to know if it is possible to develop  a video format conversion software in .net (C# or VB.net). Some one please help me...

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271003/anyone-know-of-a-set-of-c-bindings-for-ffmpeg and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191381/convert-all-video-format-to-3gp-and-mpeg4-video-format

Comment: You'd probably be best of just calling conversion software from C#. Implementing this yourself might be a lot of work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anyone know of a set of C# bindings for FFMPEG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271003/anyone-know-of-a-set-of-c-sharp-bindings-for-ffmpeg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To get started, I would check out something like [FFlib.Net](http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/) which uses MMPEG.

Comment: oke,thank u for your idea..but, i have no idea in implimenting it?

Comment: The example image on the link I provided shows you exactly how to convert from one format to another.