# convert FLV to MP4 with C#

Tags: flv, mp4

i want to convert FLV to MP4 with C#, i have vs2008.
are there any examples, or open libraries etc that i can use to achieve this?

is it possible that this be purely c# without any other external library?

thanks

Comment: See [Anyone know of a set of C# bindings for FFMPEG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271003/anyone-know-of-a-set-of-c-bindings-for-ffmpeg) for a wrapper to ffmpeg, a household name tool for video conversion

Comment: i don't understand the link you posted, it doesnt relate to me, or does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/) might help you. You may use MediaFoundation or DirectShow API to transcode and the link I shared might help you do the same form manged code. This assumed you have FLV decoder filter and H.264 encoder filers installed as MFT or DMO

Comment: that link says vista and win7 only, but i also want to support win2000 amd winxp. also an example with sample code will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Then you will need to use DirectShow - DMO

Comment: pls more info on DirectShow ?