# .NET FFmpeg wrapper for video playback

Tags: c#, .net, video, ffmpeg, video-player

Looking for an FFmpeg wrapper usable in .NET. The wrapper must support video playback with audio.

The following projects are *incomplete* FFmpeg wrappers:

http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg-sharp/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpffmpeg/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffqlay/

http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/

http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/post/fflib-net-released.aspx

ffmpeg-sharp is the closest thing I've found, but it's also incomplete (no audio in video playback).

I'm quite sure that stable proprietary wrappers do exist, so I will award the bounty to anyone willing to share the code or able to find a complete third-party version.

Comment: Check out [SharpFFmpeg](http://sharpffmpeg.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solid FFmpeg wrapper for C#/.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163036/solid-ffmpeg-wrapper-for-c-net)

Comment: Actually, this one is even older: [Anyone know of a set of C# bindings for FFMPEG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271003/anyone-know-of-a-set-of-c-bindings-for-ffmpeg/7251200#7251200)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Currently, there is no stable solution for this, so the best idea probably is to wait until someone completes it.

Comment: You should not use **"Wait untill someone completes"**. You should say **"I don't have knowledge, So try to dig in more"**.

Answer (score 7):

There is a great solution for binding FFmpeg into C#. Use the FFmpeg.Autogen from:
https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen. 
It also provides a good example when downloading the source (and it comes with precompied ffmpeg for 32 and 64 bits)!

Comment: I've used Ruslan's FFmpeg wrapper myself and it's so far the best I have found. If you need audio and video playback try my implementation of MediaElement (using AutoGen). The source code is available here: https://github.com/unosquare/ffmediaelement

Answer (score 3):

From what I know, there's no clean way to utilize ffmpeg from C# via P/Invoke, hence all these wrappers are incomplete projects. What you can do is to create a process to [ffplay.exe](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) (download under shared builds) and pass command line arguments to it. Otherwise I suggest using WPF or Silverlight MediaElement, depending on your needs; it has a pretty decent support for majority of basic tasks like video and audio playback.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [VLC Media Player](http://www.videolan.org/) yet? It is a full featured media player that uses the codecs from the FFmpeg project. You can make use of it's core functionality and there is a recently updated wrapper project on [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libvlcnet/) and a tutorial on [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/nVLC.aspx) if you want to create your own. I haven't used either of these personally, but they look fairly straight forward to use.

Comment: 1. VLC package is way too big. 2. It needs to be installed in order to work properly (same thing as installing codecs).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a thing exists and frankly the ffmpeg API is still somewhat unstable, so even if there is something today that meets your needs there is a not insignificant chance that 2 years later it will no longer work/be kept up to date.  Furthermore, marshaling data between managed and native code is relatively expensive. 99% of the time this doesn't matter, but in the case where you are dealing with media (especially uncompressed video frames) it can have a noticeable performance impact.

IMO the best way to deal with ffmpeg from C# is to write your interaction logic in C and to expose a higher level API that you can p/invoke to from C#.  This would still be the case if there was a proper low level wrapper available.

Answer (score -1):

> I'm quite sure that stable proprietary wrappers do exist

I spent a good deal of time late last year looking for one myself, without success.