# How can I extract images from a H.264 video stream?

Tags: c#, video, opencv, camera, ip-camera

How can I extract images (JPEG or PNG or ...) from a H.264 video stream preferably in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) can do that.

[You need a c# binding for ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271003/anyone-know-of-a-set-of-c-sharp-bindings-for-ffmpeg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows Media Foundadion .NET (link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mfnet/) to decode H.264. once you've done that, you can take a screencap in standard ways.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use [FFMPEG Wrapper](http://www.ffmpeg-activex.net/) and extract all the frames from the videov via C# and save them as sequence of images.  Do read about [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) on how to extract frames and save them as images too.